# compare several row in the same table to see if the status change according to time [mysql]

Tags: mysql

[this img represents two of tables i have on my mysql server one is called tlocation and the other one is temployee](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DTHsq.png)

Hello community!

i hope someone can help me with my problem.
The table 'tlocation' is used to get the record of every movement of a item in the inventory of an xxxxx organization with the column 'TRANSACTION', such movement can be assignment or release to an employee or a department. The value (6) means assignment to a department and (7) means release of a department.
I have done the association between the item and department using the employee cause i can't add another column to the table. then i search the employee's   'ID_DEPARTMENT' to filter.

Here is the thing, right now i'm trying to make a query that set as result only the elements on the table 'tlocation' that currently are assigned, that has not been release. In the img you may see that the 'ID_ITEM'= 2 is on the table two times one for an assignment and for release to the employee (3) department (3).

Thanks.

Comment: in the future avoid pictures

Comment: you could do a count, having, group by, in 6,7. So look at mysql group by `having`

Comment: i'm sorry if the picture was a problem this was my first time. May you please give me an example? i did not understand very well what you just said

Comment: well basically if you cant get to transaction 7 without getting to 6 first, and if you do a group by `having` count=1, you know it was not released if you do a `IN (6,7)`

Comment: create a sql fiddle and I will do it or someone else will

Comment: well i think this is the fiddle you told me http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8fe2fd

Comment: you want 3 rows to come back?

Comment: sorry I was looking at id not id_item

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select id_item,count(*) as theCount
from tlocation
where transaction in (6,7)
group by id_item
having theCount=1;
```

please correct for Linux case-sensitivity

the results rows are 2

```
+---------+----------+
| id_item | theCount |
+---------+----------+
|     103 |        1 |
|     176 |        1 |
+---------+----------+
```

Like I said in comments above, it assumes any 7 would have had a 6 prior. So it depends on knowing your data.

Comment: i add more information to the table 'tlocation' to do some test... i saw that if  i release the item from a department and then assigned the same item again it wont work http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/751451